# Undefined part of CSR8645 chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, bluetooth-low-energy, diagram, system-on-chip

I am trying to build a bluetooth audio headset and decided to use CSR8645 chip, but while trying to understand diagram of this chip i couldn't identify one part of it.
I am uploading picture suspicious part inside red area , so could you plese let me know if you have any clue about this part.

Best Regards

[image: Undefined object in red area]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bandpass filter. The crossed out waves tell you that frequencies above and below the passband are rejected. The legend says the passband is centred on 2.45GHz.

It's not part of the chip, but an external component.

The schematic tells you nothing more about it, such as bandwidth, insertion loss, stopband attenuation, etc. Hopefully the text has more information; I don't.

Comment: Hi Brian,thank you for your answer it makes sense.Can you check my profile to contact with me directly, want to talk with you.

Comment: Nice explanation of the symbology.